# Filter Records from JSON with Node or ES6

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm not sure the best way to go about this.  I want to iterate my `json` and find all companies that are in the US for example.  This `JSON` might get way more complex as my app grows too, as in levels, objects, etc.  I just want to know ways people are doing simple searching for filtering out subsets of data with `JSON` and `Node.js` and/or `ES6` or libraries maybe such as `Lodash`, etc.

So for example this json, what are some ways I can search it and pull back only those companies in the USA?

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Company1",
    "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company1-logo.png",
    "location":{
      "country": "USA",
      "state": "California",
      "city": "Napa"
    },
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Company2",
    "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company2-logo.png",
    "location":{
      "country": "Germany",
      "state": "",
      "city": "Berlin"
    },
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Company3",
    "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company3-logo.png",
    "location":{
      "country": "USA",
      "state": "Michigan",
      "city": "Detroit"
    },
    "active": false
  }]
```

Comment: yes I know that, but you can do node without ES6, I am simply saying use ES6 if you want for example or not, doesn't matter either way just trying to thing of ways to filter this

Comment: in other words use node middleware to help filter, or use plain JS methods, or Use fancy ES6 whatever you want for ideas or suggestions on this

Answer (score 10):

Use JavaScript native **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method with [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
var res = data.filter(v => v.location.country === 'USA');
```

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Company1",
  "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company1-logo.png",
  "location": {
    "country": "USA",
    "state": "California",
    "city": "Napa"
  },
  "active": false
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Company2",
  "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company2-logo.png",
  "location": {
    "country": "Germany",
    "state": "",
    "city": "Berlin"
  },
  "active": false
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Company3",
  "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company3-logo.png",
  "location": {
    "country": "USA",
    "state": "Michigan",
    "city": "Detroit"
  },
  "active": false
}];

var res = data.filter(v => v.location.country === 'USA');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: damn this was easier than I thought

Answer (score 4):

You can use JavaScript's simple `.filter()` method to return the list of results fulfilling the filter. Say your data is in variable data

**ES5**

```
data.filter(function(item) {
  return item.location.country === 'USA';
});
```

**ES6**: In ES6 you can use arrow functions for same as

```
data.filter((item) => {
  return item.location.country === 'USA';
});
```

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Company1",
    "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company1-logo.png",
    "location":{
      "country": "USA",
      "state": "California",
      "city": "Napa"
    },
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Company2",
    "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company2-logo.png",
    "location":{
      "country": "Germany",
      "state": "",
      "city": "Berlin"
    },
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Company3",
    "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company3-logo.png",
    "location":{
      "country": "USA",
      "state": "Michigan",
      "city": "Detroit"
    },
    "active": false
  }];

var res1 = data.filter(function(item) {
  return item.location.country === 'USA';
});

const res2 = data.filter((item) => {
  return item.location.country === 'USA';
});

console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
```

Answer (score 1):

In lodash it will be

```
_.filter(data, function(item) {
  return item.location.country === 'USA';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use native filter function.

```
const items = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Company1",
    "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company1-logo.png",
    "location":{
      "country": "USA",
      "state": "California",
      "city": "Napa"
    },
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Company2",
    "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company2-logo.png",
    "location":{
      "country": "Germany",
      "state": "",
      "city": "Berlin"
    },
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Company3",
    "logoUrl": "/lib/assets/company3-logo.png",
    "location":{
      "country": "USA",
      "state": "Michigan",
      "city": "Detroit"
    },
    "active": false
  }]

const usItems = items.filter(v => v.location.country === 'USA')
```